# Setting height for slick slider only runs after page has finished loading

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js

The slick slider is installed in this page: https://www.christmasbykrebs.com

I have set the height of the slider with this code in the external stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-height:1024px){
.slick-slide {
    height:350px !important;
}
}
```

However the issue is that while the page is loading the slider is showing for half a second with another height and then after the page finishes loading then the height I specified (350px) runs.

It seems like there is another style that is loading before the one I specified, but I have no idea where this would be. I'm assuming somewhere in the JS files?

I would like to know if there is a way to force the style I specified to run before any other.

Do you have any idea on how I can fix this so the other style that is running while loading the page does not run before the style I added?

Comment: You could try putting the style in the html file head so that it will parse that first, and can be updated later if needed

Comment: Don't show/init the widget until page loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening when a page loads is that the main file, often `index.html` is downloaded. The browsers starts reading its content, from top to bottom. In the `<head></head>` section it encounters styles and scripts and sends for each file a request out to the server to gather them. While this is going on the browser continues and comes to the `<body>` section where it starts to build up the various sections of the page. Because at this stage the browser doesn't have any styles yet (as the browser just sent the request to get them) nothing is styled yet.

To answer your question. Include any styling in the head section to ensure  that initial styling is present. You can include it like in the example below. Now, when the browser reads the main page, it reads the initial styles first and then builds the HTML document, and refines it when additional styles from stylesheets become available. I hope this helps.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    @media screen and (min-height:1024px) {
      .slick-slide {
        height: 350px !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fs-slideshow">
    <div class="slick-slide">slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slick-slide">slide 2 </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:** Try the following in the  section.

```
 @media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
  .slick-slide {
    max-height: 350px !important;
  }

  /* Likely you are able to omit the below class because we add the bottom one */
  .fs-slideshow {  
    max-height: 350px !important;
  }
  .fs-slideshow__slide {
    max-height: 350px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this information Roy. I actually tested that exact same thing. I removed the style from the external stylesheet and added it to the <head> at the very top but the same behavior is still happening.

Comment: I have set the style again on the head section. Would you be able to check if you see the same behavior happening in the website? Please reload a few times to see if you manage to see the same issue.

Comment: Hi Mel, I too see the issue, it's large first and then jumpings back to 350px. Can you try and update your CSS to be applied to `.fs-slideshow` too instead of just `.slick-slide` and replace `min-height` by `min-width`. I've updated my answer with a small UPDATE at the bottom

Comment: Hi Roy! Thanks for your help. I have added the code you sent to the head section. If you check the site the same issue happens. Please check again and you will see it. I see it still. So I don't know what is causing this issue. :/

Comment: I see the container is set to the correct height, but something within it is still larger then it supposed to be. I've updated the styling to include `overflow: hidden`. Can you try again.

Comment: That worked for the slider! Thanks so much! Another thing I noticed is that the text inside the slider has some adjustment, resulting from the slider resizing issue. While the page is loading the text shows lower (vertically centered to the original size of the slider). Then when the slider resizes to 350px the text vertically aligns to the center of that height. So it seems like the text moves from lower in the slider to higher up after loading. Is there a way to force the content div to be vertically aligned to the 350 px slider initially?

Comment: That's awesome Mel, really nice that you managed to implement that. As for the text not being centered, that's probably because another element is larger then it should. Can you add the following? I've also added the code also to my latest update in the answer `.slick-list { max-height: 350px !important; }`

Comment: Hi Roy! Thanks for your suggestion. I added it to the website but the text still "jumps". Do you have any other suggestion? Also, I know this is a little unrelated, but if it's possible that you help me understand; how do you determine which classes you need to target in order to fix an issue like this? Because this slider has many "layers", many divs, one inside the other, all with different classes. My reasoning is to target the parent element that contains all divs I need to change, but maybe I'm very wrong. Sorry if it's a complicated question!

Comment: Hey Mel, no problem and it's a very valid question, a little bit off topic of your main question, but related to the issue you are having now. As you have noticed there are many layers. Normally when this is the case you target the outer layer and place a restriction on that. With the slider, as there are so many layers, it sometimes takes a few tried to get the right one. How I tried to solve this? Open the Chrome dev tools (windows, F12 - mac, CMD+FN+I). Then go to the network tab and select Slow 3G.  This will simulate a slow connection, so you can see what is happening as the page loads.

Comment: When the error becomes visible, hit the X to stop the loading of the page and then dive into the CSS and try to correct it. As far as I could tell try this class `fs-slideshow__slide`. I've updated my answer again with the class and max-height set to 350px. Unfortunately, I cannot test the final result as when I reload the setting is gone. I hope this helps with your understanding in debugging. And this time we have the correct class.

Comment: Hi Mel, if my answer solved the problem in your question, consider marking it as accepted. This will help anyone coming across this later to know we came to a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks so much for your responses. So it seems that adding the styles to class `fs-slideshow__slide` has finally fixed the issue. I have marked the question solved. Sorry, I'm new at stackoverflow and didn't know I had to do that. I just want to thank YOU for all the time you have given me by providing suggestions, I appreciate your time and patience and please know you have been extremely helpful. I can't possibly thank you enough! :)

Comment: Ahh, thanks Mel for your kind words! I'm glad I could help and great that we finally got the right class. I indeed saw - based on your score - that you were new to Stack Overflow. No worries and thanks for accepting the answer.